# pulseaudio has no module-dbus-protocol

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I want to operate PulseAudio using DBus. In several instructions I read about using the module 'module-dbus-protocol'. But it does not exist.

```
$ pacmd load-module module-dbus-protocol
Module load failed.
```

I looked for it with autocomplete, 'pacmd list-modules', and even in the built git sources.

Is my PulseAudio properly configured? Or do I have a version problem?

Currently I use pulseaudio 5.0

EDIT:

Found, is in my /usr/lib/pulse/ folder.

Comment: was my mistake. I had the modules of two different pulsaudio versions in my /usr (/usr/local/) repositorys and my running PA was linking to to the older one.  WORKS NOW! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was my mistake. I had the modules of two different pulsaudio versions in 
- /usr/lib
-/usr/local/lib

and my running PA was linking to to the older one.

I just simply deleted all of the pulseaudio files from the /usr* repo by hand and reinstalled pulseaudio